# How to fill in missing data before basal variable and after ceiling variable (specified in data) in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have assessment data with missing data below a specific basal item and after a specified ceiling item. I'm trying to fill in a value of 1 for all missing data below the basal item and a a value of 0 for all missing data after the ceiling item. Data looks like this:

[screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09255.png)

- Line 1: need 0 for items 4 through 10
- Line 2: need 0 for items 9 and 10
- Line 3: need 1s for item 1 and 2, 0s for 9 and 10
- Line 4: need 1 for item 1
- Line 5: need 0s for item 5 through 10

Updated to add: All the items don't stay in perfect numeric it's more like: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item4b, Item4c, Item4d, Item5, Item6, Itemng1, Itemng2, Item7, Item8b, Item8c, Item9, Item10, etc.

I have been trying this:

```
VECTOR V = NCRN_1a TO NARID_nn37a.
LOOP #i=1 to 180.
DO IF (BasalTestA NE 'V(#i)').
RECODE V(#i) (0=0) (1=1) (SysmiSYSMIS=1).
END IF.
END LOOP.
```

And getting this error:

```
>On the RECODE command, the list of variables to be recoded includes the name 
>of a nonexistent variable. 
>Execution of this command stops. 
END IF. 
END LOOP
```

Comment: See my edited code - should work with your new description. Please also edit your question so the example matches the code you wrote - in order for the question to be useful for future users.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: now works with OP's edited question.

The problem with your present code arises when you try to compare a variable name to a text value. To do that you need to get the variable name as text. This is complicated to do in the loop (or requires entering all the variable names as text in a `do repeat` loop), but using restructure will do the trick more easily:

```
* creating an id for later use in restructure.
compute id=$casenum.

* restructure to long format so we have the items in a column instead of a row, and a string index with original variable names.
varstocases make val from NCRN_1a TO NARID_nn37a / index=item(val) / null=keep.

* create a variable to mark each case if it has reached 
BasalTestA yet. the same for ceiling.
compute Basl=(item=BasalTestA.
if id=lag(id) and lag(Basl)=1 Basl=1.
compute Ceil=(item=ceiling).
if id=lag(id) and lag(Ceil)=1 Ceil=1.

* now we can complete the missing items as requested.
if missing(val) and number(char.substr(item,5),F2)<basalN val=1.
if missing(val) and number(char.substr(item,5),F2)>ceilingN val=0.

* having completed the operation we can restructure to original form.
casestovars id=id/index=item/fix=BasalTestA ceiling/sep=""/drop=Basl ceil.
```

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly for what I needed

Comment: Glad to help! dont forget to [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).